# I want to know whether the Create2 can interface a LIDAR?

Tags: irobot-create, laser, lidar

I want to know if the Create 2 can interface a laser radar?
For example an [RPLidar](http://www.slamtec.com/en/lidar).

Comment: Open both of the datasheets and check the interfaces.

Comment: I don't have a create2 now, so i don't have datasheets. but i want to buy a create2. at first i have to know if the create2 can add Lidar? are there someone could tell the answer to me ?

Comment: You dont have to buy one to find its datasheet on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to work at it, adding LIDAR to the Create 2 should be possible. If you read the [iRobot Create 2 OI Specs](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/create_2_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf), you will see that you can communicate with the Create via serial communication. If you look at the datasheet for the [RPLidar](http://www.slamtec.com/download/lidar/documents/en-us/LD204_SLAMTEC_rplidar_datasheet_A2M4_v1.0_en.pdf), you will see that you can communicate with the sensor using serial communication. Because you cannot program the Create directly, you will need to use a microcontroller to interface the LIDAR and the robot.